# Converting Unbalanced Ternary Numbers to Balanced Ternary Number

Tags: number-theory

Can someone please provide a step by step algorithm for converting unbalanced ternary to balanced?

for instance:
(Base 10) 501 = (Base 3 Unbalanced) 200120

I've done some research on this conversion but I've been unsuccessful in my efforts to obtain a good understanding of the process.

I understand that 0 can be represented as "0" and 1 can be represented as "1". However, I understand 2 can be represented as "+1-1". I'm just unsure of how to use this information to produce a final result in the form of balanced ternary.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that in the $3^k$ place you can have either $1, 0, \text {or} -1$. You represent $2$ in balanced ternary with $-1$ in the current place and $+1$ in the next higher place.  $-1$ in balanced ternary will be represented by $T$ as in the [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary)  Here I will subscript unbalanced with $u$ and balanced with $b$, with all numbers in ternary.  The previous point would be that $2_u=1T_b$  To convert unbalanced to balanced, you just start from the bottom and convert each ternary digit, carrying as necessary. If you allow both $2$ and $T$ as digits, numbers have multiple representations but taking your example we can say $200120_u=2002T0=201TT0=1T01TT0_b$ and when we don't have any more $2$'s we are done.

Comment: Great job explaining this Ross M.I now understand how to convert. Can you confirm in the second sentence that it should read "You represent 2 in balanced ternary" instead of "You represent 2 in unbalanced ternary". Just wanted to clarify. If that's the case, please edit the post for other readers.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: While it might seem intuitively clear, this conversion algorithm needs a proof of termination. One way to go about proving it is to observe that, at every step, the number of digits grows by at most $1$, whereas the sum of digits decreases by $2$; as a result, if the algorithm went on for too long, the number of digits plus the sum of digits would become negative, which flies in the face of it being $\geq 0$.

Comment: Ross, how would you convert from unbalanced ternary to balanced when there is a "2" already in the left position. For instance, how would you convert 8 (base 10) = 022 (Unbalanced base 3) to (Balanced). I can convert just fine when there is a 1 or a 0 in the left position after carrying over a 2. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: A single $2$ in the most significant position is no problem-my example has one.  When you have two $2$'s in succession you have an issue I didn't resolve, but the approach is the same. From $022_u$ you make the lowest $2$ into $T$ and carry one, so $022_u=03T=10T_b$ because you replace the $3$ with $10$